# how to access local sql db from windows VM (cretaed using VMware player)

Tags: ubuntu, powerbi, virtual-machine, powerbi-desktop, vmware-player

my machine has an Ubuntu operation system and I installed sql. I need to run powerBi dashboards for testing purposes. So i created a windows VM using VM ware player. Now i need to **connect ubuntu SQL DB as powerBi data source.** Is this possible? or what are the pros and cons?

Answer (score -1):

it certainly is possible. Open the VM properties and change the network device type to bridged-networking. It will make the VM act as if it's another computer within your network. Cons: since it will be part of the network, it will be as susceptible to possible attacks and dangers that usually comes by connecting to a network.

more details here : https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html